# What does the notation $|f(A)| = X$ mean?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$A$ is a set and so is $B$.

$f$ is a function $A \to B$.

I have a math question that asks about $|f(A)|$. What does the notation $|\cdot |$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

If the elements of $ B $ are sets, then the double bars could mean [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) (i.e. the size of the set).

If $ B $ is a set of numbers, it probably means [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).

Comment: Here's the whole question:
Let A = {1,2,3,...,10} and B = {1,2,3,...,7}. How many functions f: A -> B satisfy |f(A)| = 4? How many have |f(A)| <= 4?

Comment: @mimicocotopus: Here it refers to cardinality. The first question is asking how many functions there are from $A$ to $B$ that have **exactly** $4$ elements of $B$ in their respective ranges. The second asks how many have **at most** $4$ elements of $B$ in their respective ranges.

Comment: Ah yes, I misread the question. Here $ f(A) $ refers to the *image* of $ A $ under $ f $ and so the output is always a set. So in this case, the notation must mean cardinality.